# change dropdown data - django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

How can i change the values in the department fields based on the selection made in school.
I have the below models

```
    school_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    
class Department(models.Model):
    dept_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

forms.py

```
school = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, queryset=School.objects.all(), empty_label="Select School", widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control select form-select',
            'onchange': 'this.form.submit()'
        }
    ))

    department = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, queryset=Department.objects.all(), empty_label="Select Department", widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control select form-select'
        }
    ))
```

how can i tweak my views?